# Decimal approximation to expression (square root)

Tags: python, math

I want to know if there is some module that i can transform a decimal to a root like:

```
>>> x = 1.7320508075688772
>>> f(x)
'√3'
```

As a string.
Hope you help me.

Comment: Do you mean the noun "decimal"?  "Decimate" is a verb, which means "destroy".

Comment: can you make your post a little more clearer, what actually you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this , using `math` module:

```
In [16]: strs="1,7320508075688772"

In [17]: num=float(".".join(strs.split(",")))

In [19]: math.ceil(num**2)
Out[19]: 3.0
```

**similarly:**

```
In [25]: math.ceil(1.414**2)
Out[25]: 2.0

In [26]: math.ceil(2.23606**2)
Out[26]: 5.0

In [28]: math.ceil(1.7320508075688772**2)
Out[28]: 3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I've guessed what you're asking correctly, you can use `sympy.nsimplify` [[docs]](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/simplify.html#nsimplify) to identify and then simplify the number (which uses the `identify` function of `mpmath` behind the scenes):

```
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.nsimplify(1.7320508075688772)
sqrt(3)
```

but there are lots of caveats involving precision and spurious identifications.